# TensorFlow protobuf version mismatch

Tags: c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I've install TensorFlow via `virtualenv`. And it works well.

Now I want to load model using C++ and do prediction. But I fail to compile my program because of protobuf version mismatch. Error like:

```
tensorflow/core/framework/device_attributes.pb.h:17:2: error: #error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
  ^
tensorflow/core/framework/device_attributes.pb.h:18:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please
  ^
tensorflow/core/framework/device_attributes.pb.h:19:2: error: #error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
 #error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
```

In virtualenv:

```
$ pip show protobuf
Name: protobuf
Version: 3.4.0
Summary: Protocol Buffers
```

And in shell:

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.4.0
```

I used to have `protobuf-2.6.1` in my environment but now upgrade to `3.4.0`.

ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the TensorFlow compilation process uses pulls its own distribution of protocol buffers. As of TensorFlow v1.3.0, this distribution is protocol buffers 3.3.0. If you want to mix your own C++ code with TensorFlow generated headers, you need to use that exact same version (or simply use a script to use the distribution downloaded by Bazel).

Another alternative is to generate your own headers with your own `protoc` from the original message description files.

*EDIT:*

The version of the library used by TensorFlow is currently (TF v1.9) defined in [`tensorflow/workspace.bzl`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/workspace.bzl). In principle, it should be possible to produce a custom build of TensorFlow with a particular desired version of the library changing it there, as long as it is compatible with TensorFlow and every other dependency (note that, for reasons explained in the source, there are three HTTP archives for Protocol Buffers, `protobuf_archive`, `com_google_protobuf` and `com_google_protobuf_cc`, so you would need to modify the three of them).

Comment: I've done `apt-get remove protobuf-dev protobuf-compiler` before I install protobuf from source as you mentioned. But actually there still exists a `libprotobuf.so` under `/usr/lib` while my installation was in '/usr/local/lib'. Btw there is a `libprotobuf9v5` in my ubuntu and I guess that's the reason. But uninstall it will at the same time remove gnome-desktop and other packages which is kinda wired.

Comment: @JasonRen Yes, `libprotobuf9v5` is the C++ protocol buffers runtime library in Ubuntu. It seems that Gnome is using protocol buffers itself, so it's not a good idea to remove it. You need to compile the newer version and configure the compiler and linker to pick the right headers and library (and, as I said, prefer static linking, otherwise your program will try to load the old version installed in the system and fail).

Comment: But in face the protobuf is not used by my own code. TensorFlow uses it. How can I static link a library not used directly by me?@jdehesa

Comment: Ohhh, note that the error is "by an old version"! It was "by a new version" before I install 3.4.0 which means maybe the 3.4.0 works? But the  python protobuf version is 3.4.0 too!@jdehesa

Comment: @JasonRen Ah you're right, I think I read it the other way around. The message binary format is backwards compatible, and so is the generated Python interface it seems, but not the C++ ABI, so C++ files must be generated with a `protoc` with the same version. It seems that the compilation of TF is using an older PB version; I think Bazel pulls its own dependencies, so maybe you don't have control over it. If you want to mix TF generated headers with your code you'll have to use their same version (you can also point the compiler to the files retrieved by Bazel...)

Comment: @JasonRen I just checked in my latest TensorFlow compilation (v1.3.0) and it seems they use Protobuf 3.3.0 (if using Bazel, you can find it in `bazel-tensorflow/external/protobuf`).

Comment: I replaced it with 3.3.0 and it works!!!!!!!!!!!!  `pip show protobuf` cheats me! Oh my god you save my time!!!  Many thanks!!!!!@jdehesa

Comment: Any idea how to upgrade the 'protoc' version used by the Bazel build? I'm linking together with another library requiring a newer 'protoc'

Comment: @oyd11 The version of the library is defined in the TensorFlow workspace, currently you can see it in [`tensorflow/workspace.bzl`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/workspace.bzl) (see updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the same version with `tensorflow` to recompile your proto files. You will find it in `tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf/bin/protoc` if you build `tensorflow` from source using `build_all_linux.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue which I struggled to resolve: compile script was always able to find an outdated version of protoc somewhere.

Checking protoc location:

```
which protoc # /usr/bin/protoc
sudo apt-get uninstall protobuf-compiler
conda uninstall protobuf
conda uninstall libprotobuf
exit # resign in
```

which means that there is a protoc binary `/usr/bin/protoc` and header files here `/usr/include/google/protoc`. Removing protoc installation would not necessarily remove header files inside include folder which would cause error to reappers. If you keep seeing the error after installing protobuf try cleaning include files for each protobuf locaiton.

After that feel free to download a compiled binary for your platform (in my case it was protoc-3.10.1-linux-x86_64.zip) and place it to a convenient location:

```
mkdir ~/tmp/
cd ~/tmp
wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.10.1/protoc-3.10.1-linux-x86_64.zip
sudo rm -rf ./protoc
unzip protoc-3.10.1-linux-x86_64.zip -d protoc
chmod 755 -R protoc
BASE=/usr/local
sudo rm -rf $BASE/include/google/protobuf/
sudo cp protoc/bin/protoc $BASE/bin 
sudo cp -R protoc/include/* $BASE/include
```

Despite seeing both"your protobuf version is older" and "your protobuf version is newer" during resolving the issue, simply latest version of protoc worked.