# Tensorflow c++ api

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I recently tensorflow cpp api from a way below(on MacOS Catalina ):
1. I first Install Bazel 0.23.0
2. download tensorflow:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow 
cd tensorflow  # cd to the top-level directory created
$ ./configure
```

```
bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so

# build C library
$ bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so
```

After install I run the code below:

```cpp
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/env.h"

int main(){
   return 0;
}
```

with. command below:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/libtensorflow/2.1.0_1/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/libtensorflow/2.1.0_1/lib -ltensorflow -ltensorflow_cc -ltensorflow_framework -std=c++11 main.cc -o main.o
```

but I get Error below:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libtensorflow/2.1.0_1/include/tensorflow/core/framework/device_attributes.pb.h:17:2: error: 
      This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/libtensorflow/2.1.0_1/include/tensorflow/core/framework/device_attributes.pb.h:18:2: error: 
      incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please
```

I used libprotoc 3.11.4.
what should I do? what is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TensorFlow protobuf version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235376/tensorflow-protobuf-version-mismatch)

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: Yes, I solve this and I can use Tensorflow api in cpp. You just need to change your buffer after install Tensorflow. They are matched during configuration.